# MPDF - "Auto" FontSize Textareas

Tags: php, mpdf

mPDF 7x Question:

- By default, mPDF sets a default form font size to 12pt
- When you set `$mpdf->useActiveForms = true;` it results in the left GIF example, which makes scrollbars appear when you run out of rows.
- I would like to set fonts to "Auto", which, if you do this manually within Acrobat X, results in the right GIF example.

Does Anyone know if/how this is possible?

[image]

Comment: When I drag the .pdf file into sublime, I can edit the compiled code from (left) `/F2 8.0031399729649 Tf 0.000 g` to (right) `/F2 0 Tf 0 g` and it almost works. Unfortunately setting font-size to "auto" or "0" within mpdf makes the textareas fail to render.

Comment: I have submitted a feature request to mPDF here as I doubt anyone will be able to answer this, it's likely not supported yet: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/834